# How to optimize my jquery code

Tags: jquery, html, optimization

I'm working on a new design for an organization at my college, and I've used JQuery to get my nav bar to do what I want it to do (slide down on specific nav-item click, slide back up if that or another nav-item is clicked [and slide the new nav-item down if the second case is true]).

Relevant JQuery:

```
function toggleMembers() {
if ($("#members-drop-down").is(":visible")) {
    $("#members-container").animate(
    {
        opacity: "0"
    },
    600,
    function(){
        $("#members-drop-down").slideUp();
    }
);
$("#members").removeClass('active');
}
else if ($("#about-drop-down").is(":visible")) {
    $("#about-container").animate(
        {
             opacity: "0"
        },
        600,
        function(){
             $("#about-drop-down").slideUp();
        }
    );
    $("#about").removeClass('active');
    $("#members-drop-down").slideDown(600, function(){
        $("#members-container").animate(
             {
                  opacity: "1"
             },
             600
        );
    });
    $("#members").addClass('active');
}
else if ($("#store-drop-down").is(":visible")) {
    $("#store-container").animate(
        {
             opacity: "0"
        },
        600,
        function(){
             $("#store-drop-down").slideUp();
        }
    );
    $("#store").removeClass('active');
    $("#members-drop-down").slideDown(600, function(){
    $("#members-container").animate(
        {
             opacity: "1"
        },
        600
    );
    });
    $("#members").addClass('active');
}
else {
    $("#members-drop-down").slideDown(600, function(){
        $("#members-container").animate(
              {
                    opacity: "1"
              },
              600
        );
    });
    $("#members").addClass('active');
}   
}
```

Unfortunately, though, the JQuery I wrote takes up more space than all of the HTML. How can I shorten and optimize this?

My JSFiddle [with the full code](http://jsfiddle.net/zJ8wW/).

Comment: Hows this: http://jsfiddle.net/zJ8wW/1/

Comment: Damn, that's perfect! Very clever code, my friend, and I only wish I had enough rep to upvote you or something.

Answer (score 0):

Minify your JavaScript file using one of the following:

- [JS Compress](http://jscompress.com/)
- [YUI Compressor](http://refresh-sf.com/yui/)
- [JavaScript Minifier](http://javascript-minifier.com/)